# Text on an ImageButton with css

Tags: asp.net, html, css, imagebutton

I wish to display some text on a button that has a background.  However this cannot be tied to absolute positions, since I am going to reuse this button in multiple parts of the screen, only changing the text that I am displaying.

At the moment I have the following:-

```
<div class="ReportButton">
  <div class="ReportImageButton">
      <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/button_arrow.png" ID="ImgReportButton" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" Height="40px" />
  </div>
  <div class="ReportImageButtonText">Text Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.ReportButton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.ReportImageButton {
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ReportImageButtonText {
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 330px;
  top: 330px;
}
```

This works fine however i wish to avoid using the absolute positions if possible, for the reasons I stated before.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just remove everything you have in the `ReportImageButtonText` class and it will work fine

Comment: @Johann If you like the answer by Thomas W, please accept it so that we all know that the question is answered and done with.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the CSS for ReportButton?

```
.ReportButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url("/images/button-bg.png") no-repeat top left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then, just:

```
<div class="ReportButton" onclick="doSomething();" >
    Text Goes Here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position: relative` without moving `.ReportButton` and adjust the position of the text accordingly. This will position `.ReportImageButtonText` properly within the boundary of the wrapper div

```
.ReportButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UqnE/)

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I liked Thomas reply though :)